# How to embed YouTube videos in Microsoft Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, video, embedding

How do I embed a YouTube video into Microsoft Word 2013 in the website editor?

Comment: The simplest way.  Just modify the source code manually and add the code to to embed a YouTube manually.

Comment: Insert -> Online Video?

Answer (score 3):

Once the Microsoft word 2013 is open you can navigate to Insert->Online videos.

[image]

Comment: Does this embed and store the video content offline or references it and has to stream from the net when online?